# Распознавание цифр c#

Tags: c#, tesseract

Возникла проблема с распознаванием цифр. Использовал библеотеку Emgu.CV и скачал eng.traineddata с https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/ . Цифры распознает, но через раз.
Вот пример картинки, которую над распознавать. Фон всегда одинаковый, но меняются выражения.
[image: Первое выражение]
[image: Второе]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Net;

using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.OCR;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(@"C:\test", "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined);
        
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
        Form4 form4 = new Form4();
        public Bitmap bitmap1;
        public Bitmap bitmap2;
        public Bitmap bitmap3;
        ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        public Form1()
        {
            TopMost = true;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void FormInitialize(Form form)
        {
            form.Show();
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            bitmap1 = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
            bitmap2 = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
            bitmap3 = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
        }
        #region Bot
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormInitialize(form2);
            FormInitialize(form3);
            FormInitialize(form4);
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = true;
        }
        async private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tesseract.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", " =+/*-1234567890");
            while (true)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
                Check();
                await Task.Delay(400);
            }
            
        }
        private void Check()
        {
            string text;
            getScreenshot(bitmap1, form2, 1);
            tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>($"1.jpg"));
            tesseract.Recognize();
            text = tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("%","*").Replace("В", "8").Replace("в", "8").Replace("%", "4").Replace("В", "8").Replace("=-","=");
            form2.ChangeCheckBox(GetCheckResults(text));
            textBox1.Text += text;

            getScreenshot(bitmap1, form3, 2);
            tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>($"2.jpg"));
            tesseract.Recognize();
            text = tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("%", "*").Replace("В", "8").Replace("в", "8").Replace("%", "4").Replace("В", "8").Replace("=-", "=");
            form3.ChangeCheckBox(GetCheckResults(text));
            textBox1.Text += text;

            getScreenshot(bitmap1, form4, 3);
            tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>($"3.jpg"));
            tesseract.Recognize();
            text = tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("%", "*").Replace("В", "8").Replace("в", "8").Replace("%", "4").Replace("В", "8").Replace("=-", "=");
            form4.ChangeCheckBox(GetCheckResults(text));
            textBox1.Text += text;
        }
        private static bool GetCheckResults(string mathExpressions)
        {
            try
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                string[] subExps = mathExpressions.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                int equals = int.Parse(dataTable.Compute(subExps[0], null).ToString());
                bool result = equals == int.Parse(subExps[1]);
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    private void getScreenshot(Bitmap bmp, Form form, int index) // Делаем скриншот и сохраняем его в Bitmap
    {
        form.Hide();
        Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(form.Location, new Point(0, 0), Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
        }
        bmp.Save($"{index}.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        form.Show();
    }
```

Вкратце расскажу что тут. Нажимаю кнопку и появляются формы для того,чтобы делать скриншот области.
Формы имеют красную рамку и прозрачный серый фон.
[image: 3 формы для скриншотов областей экрана]. bitmap'ы это поля, куда я сохраняю скриншоты кусков экрана. В методе Check я делаю скриншот экрана. Далее объектом(tesseract) я вызываю методы SetImage и Recognize. Нужный текст находится в `tesseract.GetUTF8Text()`. Далее я оформил чтобы мне было удобней работать. Я не знаю как передать в SetImage просто Bitmap, поэтому пришлось сделать костыль в виде сохранения Bitmap. Есть ли какой-то способ максимально точно распознавать такие выражение? Может быть есть аналогичные библиотеки? Tessnet2 пробовал, Tesseract тоже пробовал. Эта библиотека максимально точнее работает по сравнению с другими... Но все равно возникают проблемы вот с такими выражениями...

Comment: А откуда эти картинки берутся? Если на сайте, то не проще ли эти выражения брать непосредственно с сайта в виде текста?

Comment: берутся из игры.

Comment: Прогоните картинку через фильтр, который повысит контрастность. В конце концов, можно [этот фильтр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567) попробовать.

Comment: Проехать по вертикали по фоновым пикселям, получив по сегменту на каждую цифру или знак. Посчитать сумму (количество) чёрного в каждом сегменте. Для каждого символа будет характерное количество чёрного, +- погрешность