# Ошибка в алгоритме скелетизации картинки

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения, обработка-изображений

Пытаюсь скелетизировать бинаризованную картинку отпечатка пальца.
Но при скелетизации получается так, что концы отростков не заканчиваются, а уходят куда то к границам картинки (скрин прилагаю). На скрине справа - исходное изображение, слева - скелетизация бинаризованной картинки.
Не могу понять почему так происходит. Помогите найти ошибку в реализации алгоритма.

Вот сам класс скелетизации.

```
public class Skeletonizator
{
    private int[,] bitmap;

    public Skeletonizator(int[,] bitmap)
    {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public int[,] SkeletonZhangSuen()
    {
        int i, j, w, h, b, a, p1, p2, p3, p4;
        int[] p = new int[8];
        bool flag = true;

        w = bitmap.GetLength(0);
        h = bitmap.GetLength(1);
        int[,] markMap = new int[w, h];

        while (flag)
        {
            flag = false;

            /*  Подытерация 1: */
            for (i = 1; i < w - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j < h - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (bitmap[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        markMap[i, j] = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                    a = Tla(bitmap, i, j, ref p, out b);   /* Функция A */
                    p1 = p[0] * p[2] * p[4];
                    p2 = p[2] * p[4] * p[6];

                    if ((a == 1) && ((b >= 2) && (b <= 6)) &&
                            (p1 == 0) && (p2 == 0))
                    {
                        markMap[i, j] = 1;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else
                        markMap[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
            DeleteMarked(markMap, ref bitmap);

            /* Подытерация 2: */
            for (i = 1; i < w - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j < h - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (bitmap[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        markMap[i, j] = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                    a = Tla(bitmap, i, j, ref p, out b);   /* Функция A */
                    p1 = p[0] * p[2] * p[6];
                    p2 = p[0] * p[4] * p[6];

                    if ((a == 1) && ((b >= 2) && (b <= 6)) &&
                            (p1 == 0) && (p2 == 0))
                    {
                        markMap[i, j] = 1;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else
                        markMap[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
            DeleteMarked(markMap, ref bitmap);
        }

        /* Доролнительая итерация, устраняющая некоторые недочеты */
        for (i = 1; i < w - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < h - 1; j++)
            {
                if (bitmap[i, j] == 0)
                {
                    markMap[i, j] = 0;
                    continue;
                }

                Tla(bitmap, i, j, ref p, out b);   /* Функция A */

                p1 = ((p[7] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[2] * p[4];
                p2 = ((p[3] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[6] * p[0];
                p3 = ((p[1] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[4] * p[6];
                p4 = ((p[5] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[0] * p[2];

                if (p1 == 1 || p2 == 1 || p3 == 1 || p4 == 1)
                    bitmap[i, j] = 0;
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private int Tla(int[,] image, int i, int j, ref int[] p, out int b)
    {
        int m = 0, n = 0;

        p[0] = image[i - 1, j];
        p[1] = image[i - 1, j + 1];
        p[2] = image[i, j + 1];
        p[3] = image[i + 1, j + 1];
        p[4] = image[i + 1, j];
        p[5] = image[i + 1, j - 1];
        p[6] = image[i, j - 1];
        p[7] = image[i - 1, j - 1];

        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        {
            if ((p[k] == 0) && (p[k + 1] == 1))
                m++;
            n += p[k];
        }

        if ((p[7] == 0) && (p[0] == 1))
            m++;

        n += p[7];
        b = n;

        return m;
    }

    private void DeleteMarked(int[,] markBmp, ref int[,] bitMap)
    {
        int w = bitMap.GetLength(0);
        int h = bitMap.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                bitMap[i, j] -= markBmp[i, j];
    }
}
```

А вот тут вызов и конвертация `Bitmap` в `int[,]` и наобарот.

```
int[,] arr = new int[targetBitmap.Width, targetBitmap.Height];
for (int j = 0; j < targetBitmap.Height; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < targetBitmap.Width; i++)
        arr[i, j] = (targetBitmap.GetPixel(i, j) == Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255) ? 1 : 0);

Skeletonizator a = new Skeletonizator(arr);
int[,] newarr = a.SkeletonZhangSuen();

for (int j = 0; j < targetBitmap.Height; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < targetBitmap.Width; i++)
        targetBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newarr[i, j] == 1 ? Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0) : Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

pictureBox1.Image = targetBitmap;
```

Или может быть у кого то есть рабочие методы скелетизации(любой алгоритм) для примера? Буду очень благодарен.
Прилагаю оригинальный отпечаток.[image: отпечаток]
[image]

Comment: Подсказка: Посмотрите этот [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567), там в самом конце есть обычная, не векторная реализация фильтра, так вот, там показано, как через `Marshal.Copy` перегнать картинку в массив и обратно. Оно работает просто раз в 100 быстрее (буквально), чем GetPixel+SetPixel. А еще картинку можно обесцветить.

Comment: Попробуйте предварительно инвертировать картинку.

Comment: [возможно полезная ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20245003/12888024)

Comment: Кстати, вместо `int[,] arr` можно использовать `byte[,] arr`, бует кушать в 4 раза меньше памяти, ну и еще немного быстрее работать.

Comment: @aepot Прочитал все материалы, показанные вами, но к сожалению так и не смог найти решение для своей проблемы(

Comment: Отладка вас точно спасет.

Comment: Я думаю, что вряд-ли вы получите ответ, потому что для того, чтобы протестировать код, нужны данные для тестирования - оригинальная картинка, которую, к сожалению, негде взять.

Comment: @aepot Да, забыл добавить оригинальную картинку. Исправил.

Comment: Спасибо пользователю @aepot, ответ нашел в этой теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245003/zhang-suen-thinning-algorithm-c-sharp.

Comment: Вы можете заплстить рабочее решение в ответ и принять его. Это может оказаться полезным для других пользователей.

Comment: Так и хотел сделать, но почему то перенеслось в комментарии за "тривиальный ответ".

Comment: Потому что ответ-ссылка - не формат для StackOverflow. В ответе стоит привести решение именно вашего вопроса, например код, который работает правильно. И картинку, которая показывает верный результат работы этого кода. И красиво оформить, то есть дать ответ в таком же качестве, в котором у вас задан вопрос. StackOverflow - база знаний, хотите поделиться знаниями, делитесь. А ссылкой я уже поделился в комментарии, смысла просто копировать ее в ответ никакого.