# Скелетизация изображения

Tags: c#, изображения, обработка-изображений

Пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм Зонга-Суня скелетизации изображения, но что то делаю неправильно. Получаю какие то завитки, которых быть не должно.
[image: ошибка]
Как это исправить? Видимо я где то допускаю ошибку, но не могу понять где.

Вот класс скелетизации:

```
public class Skeletonizator
        {
            private int[,] bitmap;

            public Skeletonizator(int[,] bitmap)
            {
                this.bitmap = bitmap;
            }

            public int[,] SkeletonZhangSuen()
            {
                int i, j, w, h, b, a, p1, p2, p3, p4;
                int[] p = new int[8];
                bool flag = true;

                w = bitmap.GetLength(0);
                h = bitmap.GetLength(1);
                int[,] markMap = new int[w, h];

                while (flag)
                {
                    flag = false;

                    /*  Подытерация 1: */
                    for (i = 1; i < w - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (j = 1; j < h - 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (bitmap[i, j] == 0)
                            {
                                markMap[i, j] = 0;
                                continue;
                            }

                            a = Tla(bitmap, i, j, ref p, out b);   /* Функция A */
                            p1 = p[0] * p[2] * p[4];
                            p2 = p[2] * p[4] * p[6];

                            if ((a == 1) && ((b >= 2) && (b <= 6)) &&
                                    (p1 == 0) && (p2 == 0))
                            {
                                markMap[i, j] = 1;
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            else
                                markMap[i, j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    DeleteMarked(markMap, ref bitmap);

                    /* Подытерация 2: */
                    for (i = 1; i < w - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (j = 1; j < h - 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (bitmap[i, j] == 0)
                            {
                                markMap[i, j] = 0;
                                continue;
                            }

                            a = Tla(bitmap, i, j, ref p, out b);   /* Функция A */
                            p1 = p[0] * p[2] * p[6];
                            p2 = p[0] * p[4] * p[6];

                            if ((a == 1) && ((b >= 2) && (b <= 6)) &&
                                    (p1 == 0) && (p2 == 0))
                            {
                                markMap[i, j] = 1;
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            else
                                markMap[i, j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    DeleteMarked(markMap, ref bitmap);
                }

                
                for (i = 1; i < w - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 1; j < h - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (bitmap[i, j] == 0)
                        {
                            markMap[i, j] = 0;
                            continue;
                        }

                        Tla(bitmap, i, j, ref p, out b);   /* Функция A */

                        p1 = ((p[7] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[2] * p[4];
                        p2 = ((p[3] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[6] * p[0];
                        p3 = ((p[1] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[4] * p[6];
                        p4 = ((p[5] == 1) ? 0 : 1) * p[0] * p[2];

                        if (p1 == 1 || p2 == 1 || p3 == 1 || p4 == 1)
                            bitmap[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            private int Tla(int[,] image, int i, int j, ref int[] p, out int b)
            {
                int m = 0, n = 0;

                p[0] = image[i - 1, j];
                p[1] = image[i - 1, j + 1];
                p[2] = image[i, j + 1];
                p[3] = image[i + 1, j + 1];
                p[4] = image[i + 1, j];
                p[5] = image[i + 1, j - 1];
                p[6] = image[i, j - 1];
                p[7] = image[i - 1, j - 1];

                for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                {
                    if ((p[k] == 0) && (p[k + 1] == 1))
                        m++;
                    n += p[k];
                }

                if ((p[7] == 0) && (p[0] == 1))
                    m++;

                n += p[7];
                b = n;

                return m;
            }

            private void DeleteMarked(int[,] markBmp, ref int[,] bitMap)
            {
                int w = bitMap.GetLength(0);
                int h = bitMap.GetLength(1);
                for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                        bitMap[i, j] -= markBmp[i, j];
            }
        }
```

На вход подаю битмап исходной картинки приведенный в int.

```
int[,] arr = new int[targetBitmap.Width, targetBitmap.Height];
            for (int j = 0; j < targetBitmap.Height; j++)
                for (int i = 0; i < targetBitmap.Width; i++)
                    arr[i, j] = (targetBitmap.GetPixel(i, j) == Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255) ? 0 : 1);           
Skeletonizator a = new Skeletonizator(arr);
int[,] newarr = a.SkeletonZhangSuen();
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1243333/373567