# Оптимизация алгоритма расчёта CRC32 (MPEG-2) с помощью векторов

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация, crc

В процессе отладки библиотеки заметил что мой алгоритм расчёта CRC32 стал бутылочным горлышком:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод для расчёта такой:

```
public static bool CRC32V2(byte[] buffer, uint crc)
    {
        uint crc32 = 0xffffffff;
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length - 4; i++) // -4 байта так как исходный массив уже содержит CRC32
        {
            byte b = buffer[i];
            for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
            {
                if ((crc32 >= 0x80000000) != (b >= 0x80))
                    crc32 = (crc32 << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7;
                else
                    crc32 = (crc32 << 1);
                b <<= 1;
            }
        }

        return crc32 == crc;
    }
```

Во время проверки передаю CRC взятый из таблицы и массив байт этой таблицы и сравниваю.

Я пока глубоко не разбирался с векторами из `System.Numerics` и `System.Runtime.Intrinsics` поэтому перенести сходу алгоритм я не смог.

Позволит ли реализация алгоритма с использованием векторов избавится от этого горлышка или "овчинка выделки не стоит"?

Comment: https://create.stephan-brumme.com/crc32/

Comment: Вы уверены что этот метод считает CRC32 правильно? Как именно вы проверили?

Comment: [Sse42.Crc32](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse42.crc32?view=net-5.0), [Sse42.X64.Crc32](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse42.x64.crc32?view=net-5.0). https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004565/5045688

Comment: @aepot да, этот метод считает crc32 для mpeg ts пакетов верно. Проверял тем, что crc32 таблицы после мультиплексора совпадают с тем что выдаёт этот метод

Comment: Этот пост я видел, но не понял как изменить порождающий полином.

Comment: Собственно этот метод и делает проверку. Если бы crc32 считалось не верно, то ошибка была бы на каждом пакете

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov SSE 4.2 не походит, там CRC-32C. Не тот стандарт, что в MPEG-2. Я попробую векторизовать ваше решение, но пока ничего не обещаю. Если это в принципе возможно, то смысл в этом конечно же есть. Единственная проблема, рассчет идет побайтово, каждый последующий зависит от предыдущего, поэтому пачками сходу вычислять не получится. Но я еще поразбираюсь, быть может завтра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой перевод на шарп исходника на C++ https://gist.github.com/Miliox/b86b60b9755faf3bd7cf

```cs
private static readonly uint[] crc_table = new uint[]
{
    0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b,
    0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005, 0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6, 0x2b4bcb61,
    0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd, 0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7,
    0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9, 0x5f15adac, 0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75,
    0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f, 0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3,
    0x709f7b7a, 0x745e66cd, 0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039,
    0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5, 0xbe2b5b58, 0xbaea46ef,
    0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033, 0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d,
    0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe, 0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb,
    0xceb42022, 0xca753d95, 0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1,
    0xe13ef6f4, 0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d, 0x34867077, 0x30476dc0,
    0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5, 0x2ac12072,
    0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16, 0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4,
    0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca, 0x7897ab07, 0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde,
    0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c, 0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02, 0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08,
    0x571d7dd1, 0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
    0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e, 0xbfa1b04b, 0xbb60adfc,
    0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692, 0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698, 0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6,
    0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d, 0x94ea7b2a, 0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050,
    0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e, 0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2,
    0xc6bcf05f, 0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34,
    0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a, 0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80, 0x644fc637,
    0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb, 0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1,
    0x46863638, 0x42472b8f, 0x5c007b8a, 0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53,
    0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629, 0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5,
    0x3f9b762c, 0x3b5a6b9b, 0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff,
    0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623, 0xf12f560e, 0xf5ee4bb9,
    0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65, 0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b,
    0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8, 0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd,
    0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3, 0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7,
    0xae3afba2, 0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b, 0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71,
    0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74, 0x857130c3,
    0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640, 0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2,
    0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c, 0x7b827d21, 0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8,
    0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a, 0x61043093, 0x65c52d24, 0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e,
    0x18197087, 0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
    0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088, 0x2497d08d, 0x2056cd3a,
    0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654, 0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce, 0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0,
    0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb, 0xdbee767c, 0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676,
    0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18, 0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4,
    0x89b8fd09, 0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662,
    0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c, 0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668,
    0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4
};

public static uint Crc32(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data)
{
    uint crc = 0xffffffff;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc_table[((crc >> 24) ^ data[i]) & 0xff];

    return crc;
}
```

К сожалению, я не вижу возможности векторизовать этот алгоритм.

Кстати, я рекомендую вам все-таки не передавать CRC в метод для сравнения, а сравнивать снаружи метода. Так будет быстрее.

Для вашей реализации можно вызвать так

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = array;
if (Crc32(span[..^4]) == BitConverter.ToUint32(span[^4..]))
{
    // совпало
}
```

Comment: BitConverter.ToUint32(span[^4..]) выдаст нам обратный порядок байт, а  Crc32(span[..^4]) прямой.

Comment: @Deim это проблема? `span[^4..].Reverse(); BitConverter.ToUint32(span[^4..])` Я спаны вам предлагаю чисто для производительности.

Comment: это не проблема. просто у кого-то этот метод может не работать и этот кто-то будет думать, что ответный не верный.

Comment: @Deim ну подгоните логику под нужную. Я же не читал ваши спецификации. Главное - чтобы идея была понятна. Смысл спанов в том, что они компилируются в более шустрый код, без копирования данных в памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Из глубоких глубин глубокого интернета был поднят кусок кода на С в котором я нашёл табличный вариант расчёта CRC32 для стандарта MPEG-2. к сожалению первоисточника этого метода не знаю.  После некоторых доработок этот метод заработал под c#:

```
private static readonly uint[] CRC32_table = new uint[] {0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9,
                                            0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b, 0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005,
                                            0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6, 0x2b4bcb61,
                                            0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd,
                                            0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9,
                                            0x5f15adac, 0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75,
                                            0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f, 0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011,
                                            0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3, 0x709f7b7a, 0x745e66cd,
                                            0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039,
                                            0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5,
                                            0xbe2b5b58, 0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81,
                                            0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033, 0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d,
                                            0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe, 0xd9714b49,
                                            0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022, 0xca753d95,
                                            0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1,
                                            0xe13ef6f4, 0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d,
                                            0x34867077, 0x30476dc0, 0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae,
                                            0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5, 0x2ac12072,
                                            0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16,
                                            0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca,
                                            0x7897ab07, 0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde,
                                            0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c, 0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02,
                                            0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08, 0x571d7dd1, 0x53dc6066,
                                            0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
                                            0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e,
                                            0xbfa1b04b, 0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692,
                                            0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698, 0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6,
                                            0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d, 0x94ea7b2a,
                                            0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e,
                                            0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2,
                                            0xc6bcf05f, 0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686,
                                            0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34, 0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a,
                                            0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80, 0x644fc637,
                                            0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb,
                                            0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f,
                                            0x5c007b8a, 0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53,
                                            0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629, 0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47,
                                            0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5, 0x3f9b762c, 0x3b5a6b9b,
                                            0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff,
                                            0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623,
                                            0xf12f560e, 0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7,
                                            0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65, 0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b,
                                            0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8, 0xda649d6f,
                                            0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3,
                                            0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7,
                                            0xae3afba2, 0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b,
                                            0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71, 0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f,
                                            0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74, 0x857130c3,
                                            0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640,
                                            0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c,
                                            0x7b827d21, 0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8,
                                            0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a, 0x61043093, 0x65c52d24,
                                            0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e, 0x18197087, 0x1cd86d30,
                                            0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
                                            0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088,
                                            0x2497d08d, 0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654,
                                            0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce, 0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0,
                                            0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb, 0xdbee767c,
                                            0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18,
                                            0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4,
                                            0x89b8fd09, 0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0,
                                            0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662, 0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c,
                                            0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668,
                                            0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4 };



public static bool CRC32V3(byte[] buffer, uint crc)
    {
        uint result = 0xFFFFFFFF;

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length-4; i++)
        {
            result = (result << 8) ^ CRC32_table[((result >> 24) ^ (buffer[i] & 0xff)) & 0xff];
        }

        return result == crc;
    }
```

Оптимизация получилась поистине хрестоматийная. Так как в библиотеке насчитывающей более 60 классов, сотни методов и почти 8000 строк кода замена только одного, вот этого метода, позволила сократить обработку тестового файла с записанным транспортным потоком с 8.5 сек до 4.2 сек. С точки зрения оптимизации этого метода - вопрос решён. Но вот с точки зрения изучения векторизации методов - нет. @aepot возможно этот табличный вариант лучше поддастся векторизации?

Comment: Вы бы инициализацию массива-то вынесли бы за пределы метода...

Comment: @Kir_Antipov согласен. Это пока черновой вариант, просто чтобы показать что получилось))))

Comment: Я же вам сразу дал ссылку на быстрый алгоритм подсчёта. Насколько я знаю, распараллелить вычисление  crc32 нельзя. Так скмый быстрый алгоритм там просто использует большую таблицу поиска

Comment: @Alexey Ten я там не увидел crc32 под mpeg2.

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567) я писал немного теории про SIMD. Данный хэш-алгоритм невозможно вычислить в режиме SIMD, только если вы не хотите например 8 CRC32 для 8 массивов считать одновременно. А если хотите, надо сначала реализовать метод, который принимает 8 массивов и вычисляет для них CRC обычными средствами, и только потом браться за векторизацию. Очень желательно, чтобы все массивы были одинаковой или схожей длины.