# Как получить адрес памяти типа T

Tags: c#, generics, unsafe

Допустим есть тип `T where T: struct`. Как получить на него адрес памяти?

```
unsafe private void SmthMethod(T* a) {} //ошибка

unsafe private void SmthMethod2(T a)
{
   fixed(T* b = a) { } //ошибка
}
```

Comment: [C# 7.3 solved that issue with new generic constraint - unmanaged.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62251207/2881286)

Comment: зачем вообще использовать generic для неуправляемого кода, ведь даже generic math только в .NET 6 выйдет, да для нее и не нужен неупралвяемый код. Единственный случай, когда мне это реально пригодилось - это при работе с массивами, когда надо было быстро таскать данные из одномерного в N-мерный и обратно без циклов. И то, делал такое для одного из ответов. На практике и это не требуется.

Comment: @aepot забавы ради, просто интересно. Один из моих прошлых вопросов про unsafe был тоже только из-за интереса, на практике мне пока не довелось работать с подобным, да и знания лишними никогда не бывают

Comment: Хочется экстрима - [держите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо использовать следующий код:

```
class<T> where T: unmanaged
{
 
}
```

Comment: Если generic нужен только для одного метода, то вот так `private unsafe void SmthMethod2<T>(T a) where T : unmanaged { }`