# Как можно ещё оптимизировать мой код?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Код, вычисляющий количество бедрока.
Как возможно максимально быстро вычислять? Как сделать MultiThread ещё не придумал.

В мэйне идёт загрузка из файла аргументов, указывающих на: Прогресс, способ вычислений.

```
public struct Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
            List<long> args = File.ReadAllText("C:\\p.txt").Split(',').Select(long.Parse).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("Stats was successful. x - " + args[0] + ", State - " + args[4] + "/" + args[7] + ", Count - " + args[1]);
            switch (args[8])
            {
                case 0:
                    new OneThreadCPU().Start(args);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    new MoreThreadCPU().Start();
                    break;
            }
 }
}

public struct OneThreadCPU
{
    private const int MaxBlock = 0x1C9C38;
    public void Start(List<long> args)
    {
        SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), (UIntPtr)1);
        Help h = new Help();
        h.Load(new Info((int)args[0], args[1], new Point((int)args[2], (int)args[3], (int)args[4]), new Point((int)args[5], (int)args[6], (int)args[7])));
        for (; h.i.x < MaxBlock; h.i.x++)
        {
            var z = -1875000;
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (; z < MaxBlock; z++) h.i.count += h.GetBedrockChunk(h.i.x, z);
            h.Save(@"C:\\p.txt", h.i.x + 1, h.i.count, h.i.min, h.i.max, startTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern UIntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, UIntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();
}

public struct Help
{
    private const int MaxBlock = 0x1C9C38;
    public Info i;
    private readonly BedrockGen Bd = new();
    private string DateTimes() => "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss") + "] ";

    public long GetBedrockChunk(int x, int z) //-1875000,0,0,0,1000,0,0,0,0,0
    {
        var countBedrockInChunk = 0;
        var chunkSeed = Bd.rSFC(x, z);
        var vx = x >> 4;
        var vz = z >> 4;
        for (var y = (byte)1; y < 5; y++)
        for (var bx = vx; bx < vx + 16; bx++)
        for (var bz = vz; bz < vz + 16; bz++)
            if (Bd.bO112(bx, y, bz, chunkSeed))
                countBedrockInChunk++;
        if (countBedrockInChunk > i.max.count)
        {
            Send(ConsoleColor.Green,
                "Max " + "[" + countBedrockInChunk + "/" + i.max.count + "] [" + i.x + "|" + z
                 + "] [" + (i.count + countBedrockInChunk).ToString("#,#", new CultureInfo("de-DE")) + "]");
            i.max = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
        }
        else if (countBedrockInChunk < i.min.count)
        {
            Send(ConsoleColor.Red,
                "Min " + "[" + countBedrockInChunk + "/" + i.min.count + "] [" + x + "|" + z
                 + "] [" + (i.count + countBedrockInChunk).ToString("#,#", new CultureInfo("de-DE")) + "]");
            i.min = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
        }
        return countBedrockInChunk;
    }

    private void Send(ConsoleColor color, string message)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTimes() + message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public void Load(Info i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void Save(string path, int x, long countBedrockArg, Point coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg, Point coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg, DateTime dateStart, int firstArg, int secondArg)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path,
            string.Join(',',
                new List<long>{
                    x, countBedrockArg, coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg.x, coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg.z,
                    coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg.count, coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg.x,
                    coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg.z,
                    coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg.count, firstArg, secondArg
                }.Select(x => x.ToString())));
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTimes()}Save [{x}({ Math.Round((float)(100 - (float)Math.Abs(x) / MaxBlock * 100 + (x > 0 ? 50 : 0)), 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}%)] [{(new TimeSpan((DateTime.Now - dateStart).Ticks).ToString("mm'm 'ss's 'fff'n'").Replace("00s ", "").Replace("00m ", "").Replace("000n", ""))}] [{i.count.ToString("#,#", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))}]");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}


internal struct BedrockGen
{
    private const long q = 0x4F9939F508, w = 0x1EF1565BD5, e = 0x5DEECE66D, g = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    private const int t = 0xF, a1 = 0x10, a2 = 0x11;
    internal long rSFC(in int x, in int z) => ((x * q + z * w) ^ e) & g;
    private bool r(in long rs, in long a, in long b, in int y) => ((((rs * a + b) & g) >> a2) % 5) >= y;
    private int pCICN(in int x, in int y, in int z) => ((z * a1) + x) * 4 + (3 - y);
    internal bool bO112(in int x, in byte y, in int z, in long cs)
    {
        var pi = pCICN(x & t, y - 1, z & t);
        return r(cs, A_OW_112[pi], B_OW_112[pi], y);
    }
}

    public struct Info
    {
        public int x;
        public long count;
        public Point min, max;
        public Info(int x, long count, Point min, Point max)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.count = count;
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
    }

    public struct Point
    {
        public readonly int count;
        public readonly int x;
        public readonly int z;
        public Point(int x, int z, int count)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.z = z;
            this.count = count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132488/discussion-on-question-by-yotic------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю, насколько получилось правильно или нет, есть ощущение, что оно считает не так, как в однопоточке, но результат в `Save` улетает правильный. Работает примерно в 10 раз быстрее на моих 8 ядрах, но это будет сильно зависеть от возможностей процессора. Само собой, это не предел, и возможно решение вам не подойдет, но метод решения пригодится.

Как я понял, из-за того что `i.max` и `i.min` присваиваются не в том порядке, в котором это происходит при синхронных вычислениях, то происходит ряд лишних вычислений, либо просто происходит лишний вывод min/max в консоль, а с вычислениями все в порядке, но это вам будет виднее при анализе результатов.

Вы переборщили со структурами, используйте статические классы, старайтесь писать аккуратный код там, где не требуется суперпроизводительность.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long[] args = "-1875000,0,0,0,1000,0,0,0,0,0".Split(',').Select(long.Parse).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("Stats was successful. x - " + args[0] + ", State - " + args[4] + "/" + args[7] + ", Count - " + args[1]);
        OneThreadCPU.Start(args);
    }
}

public static class OneThreadCPU
{
    private static readonly ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 };
    private const int MaxBlock = 0x1C9C38;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern UIntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, UIntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

    public static void Start(long[] args)
    {
        //SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), (UIntPtr)1);
        Help h = new Help();
        h.Load(new Info((int)args[0], args[1], new Point((int)args[2], (int)args[3], (int)args[4]), new Point((int)args[5], (int)args[6], (int)args[7])));
        for (; h.i.x < MaxBlock; h.i.x++)
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            //for (int z = -1875000; z < MaxBlock; z++)
            //    h.i.count += h.GetBedrockChunk(h.i.x, z);
            Parallel.For(-1875000, MaxBlock, parallelOptions, z =>
            {
                Interlocked.Add(ref h.i.count, h.GetBedrockChunk(h.i.x, z));
            });
            h.Save(@"p.txt", h.i.x + 1, h.i.count, h.i.min, h.i.max, startTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}

public struct Help
{
    private static readonly CultureInfo deDE = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    private const int MaxBlock = 0x1C9C38;
    public Info i;
    private string DateTimes() => "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss") + "] ";
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public long GetBedrockChunk(int x, int z) //-1875000,0,0,0,1000,0,0,0,0,0
    {
        int countBedrockInChunk = 0;
        long chunkSeed = BedrockGen.rSFC(x, z);
        int vx = x >> 4;
        int vz = z >> 4;
        for (byte y = 1; y < 5; y++)
            for (int bx = vx; bx < vx + 16; bx++)
                for (int bz = vz; bz < vz + 16; bz++)
                    if (BedrockGen.bO112(bx, y, bz, chunkSeed))
                        countBedrockInChunk++;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (countBedrockInChunk > i.max.count)
            {
                Send(ConsoleColor.Green,
                    "Max " + "[" + countBedrockInChunk + "/" + i.max.count + "] [" + i.x + "|" + z
                        + "] [" + (i.count + countBedrockInChunk).ToString("#,#", deDE) + "]");
                i.max = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
            }
            else if (countBedrockInChunk < i.min.count)
            {
                Send(ConsoleColor.Red,
                    "Min " + "[" + countBedrockInChunk + "/" + i.min.count + "] [" + x + "|" + z
                        + "] [" + (i.count + countBedrockInChunk).ToString("#,#", deDE) + "]");
                i.min = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
            }
        }
        return countBedrockInChunk;
    }
    private void Send(ConsoleColor color, string message)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTimes() + message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public void Load(Info i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void Save(string path, int x, long countBedrockArg, Point coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg, Point coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg, DateTime dateStart, int firstArg, int secondArg)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path,
            string.Join(',',
                new long[]{
                    x, countBedrockArg, coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg.x, coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg.z,
                    coordinatesMinBedrockCountArg.count, coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg.x,
                    coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg.z,
                    coordinatesMaxBedrockCountArg.count, firstArg, secondArg
                }));
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTimes()}Save [{x}({ Math.Round((float)(100 - (float)Math.Abs(x) / MaxBlock * 100 + (x > 0 ? 50 : 0)), 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}%)] [{(new TimeSpan((DateTime.Now - dateStart).Ticks).ToString("mm'm 'ss's 'fff'n'").Replace("00s ", "").Replace("00m ", "").Replace("000n", ""))}] [{i.count.ToString("#,#", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))}]");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}


internal static class BedrockGen
{
    #region Vars

    private static readonly long[] A_OW_112 =
    {
       // ...
    };

    private static readonly long[] B_OW_112 =
    {
       // ...
    };
    #endregion

    private const long q = 0x4F9939F508, w = 0x1EF1565BD5, e = 0x5DEECE66D, g = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    private const int t = 0xF, a1 = 0x10, a2 = 0x11;

    internal static long rSFC(in int x, in int z) => ((x * q + z * w) ^ e) & g;
    private static int pCICN(in int x, in int y, in int z) => ((z * a1) + x) * 4 + (3 - y);
    private static bool r(in long rs, in long a, in long b, in int y) => ((((rs * a + b) & g) >> a2) % 5) >= y;
    internal static bool bO112(in int x, in byte y, in int z, in long cs)
    {
        var pi = pCICN(x & t, y - 1, z & t);
        return r(cs, A_OW_112[pi], B_OW_112[pi], y);
    }
}

public struct Info
{
    public int x;
    public long count;
    public Point min, max;
    public Info(int x, long count, Point min, Point max)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.count = count;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
}

public struct Point
{
    public readonly int count;
    public readonly int x;
    public readonly int z;
    public Point(int x, int z, int count)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

`A_OW_112` и `B_OW_112` выкинул из кода, не влезали в ответ.

Вывод в консоль без многопоточки был 26-28 сек, с многопоточкой 3 сек, то есть ~x10

```
Stats was successful. x - -1875000, State - 1000/0, Count - 0
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [524/0] [-1875000|0] [524]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [508/1000] [-1875000|1] [1.032]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [538/524] [-1875000|2] [1.570]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [502/508] [-1875000|5] [3.121]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [479/502] [-1875000|6] [3.600]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [473/479] [-1875000|9] [6.654]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [540/538] [-1875000|14] [9.750]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [542/540] [-1875000|-1640619] [19.520]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [545/542] [-1875000|-1406235] [55.907]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [552/545] [-1875000|-1406212] [103.443]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [468/473] [-1875000|-703105] [132.064]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [557/552] [-1875000|-234363] [137.208]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [561/557] [-1875000|-234177] [777.769]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [464/468] [-1875000|-468516] [924.236]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [564/561] [-1875000|-1874688] [1.918.448]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [450/464] [-1875000|-1405662] [3.257.131]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [569/564] [-1875000|-1170389] [5.677.585]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [575/569] [-1875000|-700815] [10.923.967]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [449/450] [-1875000|-640628] [269.409.791]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Min [447/449] [-1875000|82120] [343.133.391]
[21.12.20.20:35:12] Max [576/575] [-1875000|-378142] [413.792.142]
[21.12.20.20:35:13] Min [445/447] [-1875000|-121064] [515.594.194]
[21.12.20.20:35:13] Max [578/576] [-1875000|-1055406] [588.187.774]
[21.12.20.20:35:14] Max [579/578] [-1875000|-982455] [996.807.888]
[21.12.20.20:35:15] Max [581/579] [-1875000|1624880] [1.791.911.611]
[21.12.20.20:35:15] Save [-1874999(5E-05%)] [03s 559n] [1.919.984.172]
[21.12.20.20:35:15] Min [441/445] [-1874999|-1636923] [1.934.725.577]
[21.12.20.20:35:19] Save [-1874998(0,00011%)] [03s 507n] [3.840.006.748]
[21.12.20.20:35:19] Min [437/441] [-1874998|-1837993] [4.027.758.271]
[21.12.20.20:35:19] Max [584/581] [-1874998|-1132272] [4.059.928.818]
[21.12.20.20:35:21] Max [585/584] [-1874998|1009530] [5.316.895.803]
[21.12.20.20:35:22] Save [-1874997(0,00016%)] [03s 498n] [5.760.010.912]
```

`SetThreadAffinityMask` - примерно бесполезная тема, как я и предполагал, избавьтесь от неё.

Ну и по мелочи подчистил код, где в глаза бросилось.

---

UPD: Увидел, в чем разница в поведении. Дело в том, что распараллеленный код находит при одинаковом количестве бедрока случайный чанк, а не первый по z. Поэтому z координата может отличаться от синхронного кода. Чтобы это исправить, можно накатить вот такой патч.

```cs
lock (_lock)
{
    if (countBedrockInChunk > i.max.count)
    {
        Send(ConsoleColor.Green,
            "Max " + "[" + countBedrockInChunk + "/" + i.max.count + "] [" + x + "|" + z
                + "] [" + (i.count + countBedrockInChunk).ToString("#,#", deDE) + "]");
        i.max = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
    }
    else if (countBedrockInChunk < i.min.count)
    {
        Send(ConsoleColor.Red,
            "Min " + "[" + countBedrockInChunk + "/" + i.min.count + "] [" + x + "|" + z
                + "] [" + (i.count + countBedrockInChunk).ToString("#,#", deDE) + "]");
        i.min = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
    }
    else if (countBedrockInChunk == i.max.count && i.max.z > z)
    {
        i.max = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
    }
    else if (countBedrockInChunk == i.min.count && i.min.z > z)
    {
        i.min = new Point(x, z, countBedrockInChunk);
    }
}
```

Вот теперь результаты вывода в файл в точности совпадают с вашими.

Comment: Почему вы используете static? разве он не будет медленее? 
Можете скинуть выходные данные при первой проверке -1874999?

Comment: Что за lock? Вперые вижу

Comment: @Yotic `-1874999,1919984172,-1875000,-121064,445,-1875000,1624880,581,0,0` улетает в первый Save. `lock` - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: @Yotic да, вижу, что не совсем то что нужно получилось, жаль.

Comment: Я догадываюсь в чём проблема, сейчас открою код, он неправильно считывает координату z

Comment: @Yotic Давайте лучше в чате обсудим, ссылка под вашим вопросом, а то модераторы будут ругаться.

Comment: Я нашёл ошибку, она не должна сработать при сохранении в файл, скиньте данные именно из файла

Comment: @Yotic так я из файла вам и скинул.

Comment: @Yotic дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, скорость увеличилась в 3 раза [20s], процессор сжирает, но ОС работает без игр нормально

Comment: @Yotic здесь можно еще немного оптимизаций добавить, например развернуть в одну формулу методы `BedrockGen`, тогда можно будет избавиться от нескольких лишних математических операций при вычислениях. Потом есть такой аттрибут для методов `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`, он мне прироста по перфу не дал, поэтому не стал показывать, но вы поизучайте. Ну и наконец, есть SIMD, [выглядят они так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567). Задачи непростые, но если постараться, то еще раза в 2-3 можно поднять перф.

Comment: Думаю вы точно слышали об хеше функций, когда при входе одинаковых входных данных идёт оптимизация, разве это не лучше?

Comment: @Yotic хэш тоже надо время, чтобы посчитать. Но я не вникал в суть того, что делает ваш код, разве что слегка. Так что вам виднее.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132528/discussion-between-yotic-and-aepot).