# Получение текста с картинки (OCR) C#

Tags: c#, распознавание-символов

подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку которая бы смогла определять текст на картинке с фоном. На данный момент использую библиотеку IronOcr, но к сожалению она не всегда верно определяет текст, либо вообще не определяет. Пример кода:

```
  private string GetTextFromImg(Image image, bool NeedToCrop = true, string FileLocation = "", Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(), int Attempt = 1)
        {
            if(NeedToCrop)
            {
                Image CropedImg = this.cropImage(image, rect);

                CropedImg.Save("Frame_croped.jpg");
                var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
                Ocr.Configuration.WhiteListCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-/";
                Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.EnglishFast;

                using (var Input = new OcrInput("Frame_croped.jpg"))
                {
                    Input.DeNoise(); // use if image contains digital noise#
                    Input.Contrast();
                    string Result = Ocr.Read(Input).Text;

                    if ((Attempt == 1 && Result == "" && image.Width == 320 && image.Height == 252) || (Attempt == 1 && !Result.Contains("-")))
                    {
                        rect = new Rectangle(84, 115, 153, 26);

                        Result = this.GetTextFromImg(image, true, "", rect, 2);
                    }
                    return Result;
                }
            }    
        }
    
       private Image cropImage(Image image, Rectangle cropArea)
            {
                Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(image);
                return bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
            }
```

В данном случает я "в ручную" обрезаю изображение, чтобы оставить чисто текст на картинке. Но данный случай не всегда работает, так как текст может быть не всегда по центру. Может кто-то подсказать какую-нибудь библиотеку которая сможет определять текст без обрезания? Пробовал библиотеку tessnet2, но хороших результатов добиться не удалось. Изображения прилагаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я полагаю, надо разобраться в двух вопросах: 1) использовать последнюю версию OCR библиотеки 2) использовать наиболее подходящую под вашу задачу нейронку. С показанным кодом здесь делать особо нечего. Можно еще попробовать обесцветить картинку, но не уверен, что это поможет.

Comment: Какую нейронку можете посоветовать? И каким способом быстро обесцветить картинку?

Comment: Пример обесцвечивания есть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567), есть простой, есть векторный. С нейронками плохо знаком, смотрите по отзывам, готовых разных много должно быть.