# Изменить пиксель на png картинке в виде массива байтов

Tags: c#, png, bytearray

Нужно сделать цикл, в котором ОЧЕНЬ быстро создавать новую картинку в виде старой с чёрным пикселем в определённом месте в формате png. Картинка должна быть **обязательно** в png формате 
Bitmap будет медленным.

Пробовал на обычном png картинке с помощью байт-редактора HxD - ничего не получилось, часто я только портил картинку без изменений цвета пикселей

Comment: Png - сжатый формат, типа Zip архива, только для пикселей. HEX редактором или заменой байт ничего не получится. Вы же понимаете, что такое сжатие данных? Если вам нужна производительность - давайте воспроизводимый пример, который работает и требования, которые он не выполняет. Чтобы заменить данные в архиве, надо распаковать-заменить-запаковать.

Comment: @aepot, понимаю, как я понимаю, у png есть свои регионы, примерно по 4x4 пикселя, мне бы хватило и их изменения

Comment: Я только начал делать, даже рабочего кода нет

Comment: Вы сказали, что битмап медленный, и как решение не подходит. Покажите медленный битмап, по которому вы выяснили, что он не подходит, я сделаю вам быстрый. А по поводу регионов, [вы неправы](https://blog.underpowered.net/how-does-it-work/png-deflate/).

Comment: Просто чтобы мне его использовать мне нужно: 1) Создать bitmap через файл 2) Изменить пиксель 3) Сохранить bitmap в виде файла png 4) Прочесть этот файл как массив байт 5) Сделать с этим массивом байтов что-то дальше, что мне нужно 6) Снова открывать этот файл как bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот маленький сниппет, как заменить пиксель в PNG

```
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new();

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using var stream = await _client.GetStreamAsync("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WY0S.png");
    using var bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);

    SetPixel(bmp, Color.Red, 10, 10);
    bmp.Save("yotic.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}

private static unsafe void SetPixel(Bitmap bmp, Color color, int x, int y)
{
    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    int* ptr = (int*)bmpData.Scan0;
    ptr[y * bmpData.Width + x] = color.ToArgb();
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

Надеюсь, видно красный пиксель на аватарке автора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже 3-ий час пробую сделать на bitmap. Я видел что у Save есть флаги, думаю что нужно их так же использовать чтобы убрать полностью сжатие. Можете дать какие-нибудь контакты чтобы связаться?

Comment: @Yotic я не контачу ни с кем с SO и менторством не занимаюсь, совсем. Вот вам [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567) и если надо очень много пикселей перекрасить и очень быстро, то вот [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567).

Comment: Save каждый раз писать нужно? Или всё же магическим образом там всё само заменится? Я думаю просто на Stream заменить

Comment: @Yotic этот код - практически эквивалент `Bitmap.SetPixel` и он действительно медленный, а вот если вам надо много пикселей за раз поменять, то если написать код между `LockBits` и `UnlockBits`, то время выполнения практически не изменится. Грубо говоря, можно всю картинку перекрасить очень быстро, будет гораздо быстрее, чем через `Bitmap.SetPixel` в цикле.

Comment: @Yotic вы можете сохранить в поток не сохраняя на диск `using var ms = new MemoryStream(); bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); ms.Position = 0;`, в 3 строки кода. Далее делайте с `ms` что хотите, хотите в массив байт `ms.ToArray()`, хотите - передавайте в сеть и т.д. Магическим образом ничего не заменится.

Comment: У меня именно такой код :D, только я до сих пор не могу понять как сделать что-то около счётчика через массив Color... Вероятно задам вопрос и сделаю его конкурсным(Если у меня есть права), голова уже 3 часа не парит

Comment: @Yotic я же и спрашивал, что именно вам нужно. Вы просили пиксель - я дал пиксель. Если ответ был полезен - вы знаете, что делать. :) Чтобы получить другой ответ, надо задать другой вопрос, выдав максимум деталей туда, чтобы вообще понятно было, в чем задача.

Comment: Вероятно это - единственный верный ответ, только если не найти всё же способ как-то сделать png картинку без компрессии и отдельных замудренностей

Comment: @Yotic Png без компрессии - это по сути Bmp. С разницей только в том, что первый поддерживается не везде, а второй - везде.

Comment: Мне обязательно нужен png, т.к я ищу определённый хэш png картинки (MD5 8 или 16 нулевых байтов в начале) Хэш беру из файла

Comment: @Yotic с этого и начинать надо было. Задайте отдельный вопрос. Приведите пример изначальной картинки, ее размеры и т.д. MD5 - это кстати всего 16 байт.

Comment: Да, но часть приложений использует часть MD5, то есть 8 байт из 16

Comment: @Yotic еще надо понять, из чего MD5 вычисляется, из пикселей или из сжатой картинки, вы точно ничего не перепутали? Логичнее было бы как раз первое, а не второе, как вы считаете.

Comment: Ясно же что из байтов, берётся же готовый файл в виде стрима