# RayCast: узнать точку пересечения отрезка и rectangle (прямоугольника)

Tags: c#

мне надо как то узнать в какой точке находится пересечение отрезка и Rectangle, нашел такой метод на этом сайте bool LineIntersectsRect, который разбивает Rectangle на 4 отрезка и проверяет их пересечение с нашим отрезком bool LineIntersectsLine. Да факт пересечения он возвращает в формате true/false, но проблема в том что мне нужно узнать в какой точке луч столкнулся с объектом

```
    static public List<GameObject> castedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    public void Cast(World world)
    { 
        castedObjects.Clear();
        
        PointF start = new PointF(From.x, From.y);
        PointF end = new PointF(toX,toY);
        
        for(int j = 0; j < world.CurrentMap.Count; j++)
        {
            RectangleF objectBounds = world.CurrentMap[j].Bounds;
            
            if (LineIntersectsRect(start,end,objectBounds))
            {
                castedObjects.Add(world.CurrentMap[j]);
            }
        }            
    }
    
    static bool LineIntersectsRect(PointF p1, PointF p2, RectangleF r)
    {
        return LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new PointF(r.X, r.Y), new PointF(r.X + r.Width, r.Y)) ||
            LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new PointF(r.X + r.Width, r.Y), new PointF(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
            LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new PointF(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height), new PointF(r.X, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
            LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new PointF(r.X, r.Y + r.Height), new PointF(r.X, r.Y)) ||
            (r.Contains(p1) && r.Contains(p2));
    }
    
    static bool LineIntersectsLine(PointF l1p1, PointF l1p2, PointF l2p1, PointF l2p2)
    {
        float q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y);
        float d = (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y) - (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X);

        if( d == 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }

        float r = q / d;

        q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y);
        float s = q / d;

        if( r < 0 || r > 1 || s < 0 || s > 1 )
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Используйте метод Лианга-Барски. [Толковый код на С](https://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/clipping.html). В вашем методе можно найти точки пересечения, используя полученные параметры r или s, если они в пределах 0..1

Comment: Совет, вместо `PointF` используйте [Vector2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2), суть ровно та же, те же 2 флоата внутри, но он поддерживает векторные вычисления, и по-моему даже имеет аппаратное ускорение этих вычислений.

Comment: я просто свой RayCast движок решил попробовать сделать на GDI+

Comment: Оказалась буква s это расстояние до объекта в процентах, r скорее всего это растояние в процентах с начала обьекта до точки попадания луча

Comment: Кстати, [Vector3](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3) тоже есть. GDI+ или нет, это не важно, я Ray Tracing софтовый по приколу писал на GDI+, на среднем калькуляторе с двумя зеркальными шарами 60 FPS для кадра 800x600 в многопоточке на 4 ядрах получал, тогда как без них - в 4 раза меньше. Где-то даже проект валяется.

Comment: @aepot ого, а gdi поддерживает много поточность разве? Ну в плане можно на одном Graphics рисовать в разных потоках? У меня был опыт, когда я писал игру на двоих и там один поток рендерел экран для игрока 1, другой для игрока два. Ну правда мне приходилось дублировать объекты Image для разных потоков, обьекты Pen, Brush и т.д., чтобы не возникала ошибка.

Comment: Можно с битмапом работать как с массивом байт в скольких угодно потоках, GDI+ тут особо не при чем. Я рисую битмап и закидываю потом готовый в интерфейс через UI поток. Рендер попиксельный, никакие Graphics я не использую, они для 2D, а у меня 3D.

Comment: @aepot понял, спасибо. Идея хорошая. Я таким образом фото редактор с фильтрами как то делал, не додумался сразу, что можно этот метод использовать для рисования игры. Метод на самом деле очень интересен тем, что можно пост эффекты будет накладывать без особых потерь производительности.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1219811/373567