# Как работает оператор == для строк?

Tags: c#, clr

`System.String` перегружает операторы `==` и `!=`, но оба они вызывают метод [`Equals`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Comparison.cs,372d790ddae4cbb4). Первая часть этого метода понятна, сравниваются ссылки/длина/на null. Но вторая часть для меня остаётся непонятной. Вызывается метод [`SpanHelper.SequenceEquals`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/SpanHelpers.Byte.cs,998a36a55f580ab1). Что он делает? Туда передается только первый `char` сравниваемых строк, кастуется к `byte`, а дальше ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прошу прощения, если я объясняю очевидную вещь,

но, по моему, там довольно понятный алгоритм:

после сравнения ("что если оба null - о! надо вернуть true!")

происходит сравнение длинн строк. Длинны не равны? - возвращаем false!

И у нас остался один вариант, когда длинны двух строк равны.

Тогда вызывается оптимизированная версия сравнения последовательностей - этот самый SequenceCompareTo()

Первый байты передаются вот почему: так как там всё помечено Unsafe, то взяв первый байт и зная длинну, можно бежать по последовательности байтов, делая инкремент индекса (и из за ансейва не боясь стукнуться о границу последовательности и получить exception)

Как то так.

Конечно, такие хитрые преобразования типов мне и в страшном сне бы не приснились, но выглядит всё довольно логично.

я немного удивлён другим - именно побайтовым сравнением, без перехода на команды процессора, работающие с 64-битными словами...

Comment: `побайтовым сравнением` - практически наверняка будет работать SIMD часть алгоритма, так как найти сейчас процессор без поддержки SSE/AVX практически нереально. Так что можно считать, что побайтового там нет вообще.

Comment: @aepot - да, было подозрение, что там уже оптимизирует компилятор...

Comment: Компилятор тут не при чем, прямо по ссылке у автора код, вы же в него смотрели?

Comment: @aepot - прошу прощения, я смотрел, я просто не понял, что это назвается  "SIMD часть"

Comment: Векторные вычисления, почитайте про SIMD как технологию, там просто для понимания. Ну или [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567).

Comment: @aepot - спасибо!