# Быстрый вывод на PictureBox WInForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Я делаю игру Конвея "Жизнь" в WinForms, понимаю что не лучшая платформа, но с базовый функционалом все отлично. Я ускорил алгоритм просчета нового поколения, до 20-15мс на поколение(1890х1080 размер массива) . Но на сам PictureBox, я не могу вывести такое кол-во клеток. Каждая живая клетка рисуется на PictureBox. При высоком разрешении скорость отрисовки примерно 200-150мс на одно поколение. Вопрос можно ли ускорить вывод на PictureBox. Я пробовал выводить только изменившиеся клетки это особо не помогло.

Есть ли какие-то варианты оптимизации вывода на PictureBox? Или возможно на winforms не ускорить вывод не залезая в какие-нибудь дебри.

Код вывода

```
graphics.Clear(BackGroundColor);
            for (int x = 1; x < GameEngine.Cols - 1; x++)
                for (int y = 1; y < GameEngine.Rows - 1; y++)                    
                    if (GameEngine.Map[x + y * GameEngine.Cols] == 0b_0001)              
                                graphics.FillRectangle(
                            CellColor, (x + X) * Resolution * Range, (y + Y) * Resolution * Range,
                            (Resolution * Range) - GridSeting,
                            (Resolution * Range) - GridSeting);   
                 
            pictureBox.Refresh();
```

Привязка обьекта Graphics к PictureBox

```
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
            graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox.Image);
```

---

Результат по рекомендации из ответа получился такой

Метод Bits.Lock + Unsafe + Parallel

```
unsafe{
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                Parallel.For(0, bmpData.Height, y  =>
                {
                    byte* currentLine = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0 + (y * bmpData.Stride);

                    int pos = 0;
                    for (int x = 2; x < bmpData.Width * 3; x += 3){
                        if(GameEngine.Map[pos + y * bmpData.Width] == 1) currentLine[x] = (byte)255;
                        pos++;
                    }
                });
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `FillRectangle` - это один пиксел выводится? | [Bitmap.LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) - работайте напрямую с байтами изображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала надо на битмапе рисовать, а потом готовый засовывать в `PictureBox`.

Пусть сам битмап будет фиксированного размера, а клетка - один пиксель, и пусть `PictureBox` сам растягивает этот битмап, при увеличении пиксели превратятся в квадратики.

Как очень быстро работать с битмапами через `LockBits`, я показывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567) (самое начало ответа). Суть работы с картинкой как с массивом, это формула
`индекс = (x + y * ширина) * количество байт на пиксель`

---

Вот, немного доработал код, возможно будет побыстрее

```
unsafe
{
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int chunksCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
    int chunkHeight = bmp.Height / (chunksCount - 1);
    Parallel.For(0, chunksCount, chunk =>
    {
        int y = chunkHeight * chunk;
        byte* currentLine = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0 + y * bmpData.Stride;
        int actualHeight = Math.Min(chunkHeight, bmpData.Height - y);
        for (int i = 0; i < actualHeight; i++)
        {
            int mapOffset = (y + i) * bmpData.Width;
            int pos = 0;
            for (int x = 2; x < bmpData.Width * 3; x += 3)
            {
                if (GameEngine.Map[pos + mapOffset] == 1) 
                    currentLine[x] = (byte)255;
                pos++;
            }
            currentLine += bmpData.Stride;
        }
    });
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

Comment: Я применил выш способ. Используя unsafe + Parallel и добился 36 мс на картинку 1920х1080. Это максимум или я что-то не так сделал

Comment: @SevaVorobev отличный результат для скалярного кода, есть еще векторы, SIMD операции, тема сложная, но вдруг заинтересует ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567)).

Comment: @SevaVorobev кстати, попробуйте без распараллеливания, сдается мне, что он не дает прироста в производительности, или дает, но совсем немного. Запуск потоков и переключение между ними - дорогая операция, котороая в масштабах нескольких миллисекунд - просто огромна.

Comment: спасибо большое за идею с Bits.Lock. Про SIMD инструкции, я читал еще на Habr, где они ускоряли вычисления. Думаю надо ускорять вычисления одного поколения, потому что сейчас вычисления примерно 17мс.

Comment: Без Parallel скорость примерно 40мс

Comment: @SevaVorobev я добивался применения достаточно сложного фильтра к изображению 1920x1080, то есть сложного изменения каждого его пикселя за 4мс. Никакое распараллеливание не даст такого времени, так как взятие одного потока из пула - это уже пара миллисекунд. Лучше результат будет в одном потоке. Как видите, разницы почти нет. Только в одном случае у вас одно ядро работает, а во втором все 4, то есть получив 4мс вы нагрузили машину намного сильнее.

Comment: @SevaVorobev либо попробуйте параллелить не построчно, а по 100 строк на поток например. Будет намного бодрее.

Comment: @SevaVorobev добавил в ответ доработанный код. Кстати, если `GameEngine.Map` это массив, и если узнать что там внутри, и как это должно выглядеть, можно залить это в битмап чуть ли не моментально. Но не зная, из чего нужно что получить, будет сложно. Если интересно, можете задать отдельный вопрос, показав текущий рабочий код, то как создаете битмап и как копируете в него данные. У меня есть подозрение, что можно это копирование уложить в пару мс вообще без потоков.

Comment: @SevaVorobev прошу прощения, увидел баг, поправил `(y + i)`. Еще вынес вычисление смещения `mapOffest` за пределы цикла.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462076/Оптимизация-кода-winforms-c

Comment: Разница примерно в 2мс. С вашим кодом и моим

Comment: @SevaVorobev это еще раз доказывает, что распараллеливание здесь не очень эффективно.

Comment: я выложил код в отдельный вопрос, возможно вы что-то заметить что можно оптимизировать. Заранее огромное спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462076/Оптимизация-кода-winforms-c?noredirect=1#comment2614585_1462076