# Оптимизация вывода массива в Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms

Игра жизнь. Работаю над своим курсовым проектом.
В основном проекте, можно менять правила подсчета соседей, рождение и смерть клеток. Масштаб карты. Рисовать свои схемы. Сохранять и открывать схемы.
Но хочется оптимизировать этот код чтобы можно было добиться 60fps в 1920х1080

Скорости которые я имею сейчас.

Разрешение: 1920х1080

Скорость подсчета нового поколения: 16-18мс

Скорость обработки и вывода картинки: 33-36мс

Кол-во поколений в секунду: 20.

Без вывода картинки и обработки, кол-во поколений в секунду примерно 60-70.

Создание обьекта BitMap и GameEngine

```
 int widht = 1920;
            int height = 1080;

            engine = new GameEngine(
                rows: height,
                cols: widht);
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(widht, height);
pictureBox.BackgroundImage = image;
```

Изменение картинки

```
unsafe{
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            
                Parallel.For(0, bmpData.Height, y  => {
                    byte* currentLine = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0 + (y * bmpData.Stride);
            
                    int pos = 0;
                    for (int x = 2; x < bmpData.Width * 3; x += 3){
                        if(GameEngine.Map[pos + y * bmpData.Width] == 1) currentLine[x] = 200;
                        pos++;
                    }
                });
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            
            }
```

Таймер в 1 мс

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            engine.NewGeneration();

            BitMapChenged.ImageChenged(image);
            
            pictureBox.Image = image;
            pictureBox.Refresh();

            graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            graphics.Clear(Color.Black);

        }
```

пов: Использование обьекта Graphics для того чтобы очистить картинку перед новым поколением. Без очистки скорость несильно увеличивается

Comment: Что именно хотите оптимизировать?

Comment: И подсчет и вывод картинки. Вы сказали что можно оптимизировать код

Comment: Вырезали методы из кода, не объяснили что за переменные используются. Что такое `GameEngine.Map`? Как создается битмап, как ему задаются размеры? Зачем очищать битмап, если можно создать новый? Это же быстрее. Что такое `image`? Этот код невозможно оптимизировать, так как неизвестно, как его части связаны между собой.

Comment: _И подсчет и вывод картинки._ давайте начнем с чего-то одного, здесь есть правило, один пост - один вопрос, а у вас целых два, получается. Конретизируйте, что именно надо оптимизировать.

Comment: Ответил про картинку, про генератор можете задать отдельный вопрос. Но сначала до конца разберитесь с картинкой.

Comment: Вопрос про оптимизацию подсчета соседей. Описал как можно подробно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462108/Оптимизация-Игры-Жизнь-winforms-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте начнем с копирования картинки.

Так как 1920 делится на 4 нацело (это важно), то `Stride` будет равен `Width`, в конце строки битмапа не будет паддинга. То есть ниже приведенное решение не будет работать для битмапов, ширина которых не кратна четырем. Предлагаю использовать 8-битный битмап, так как в нем один пиксель это один байт и исходный массив с данными можно скопировать в битмап вообще без изменений.

Пример создания такого битмапа:

```
public Bitmap CreateGrayscaleBitmap(int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;
    for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
        pal.Entries[c] = Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);
    bmp.Palette = pal;
    return bmp;
}
```

```
Bitmap bmp = CreateGrayscaleBitmap(1920, 1080);
```

Здесь завдена серая палитра, то есть цвет 0 - черный, 255 - белый, все что между ними - градации серого. То есть в результирующий массив при генерации данных вы можете складывать сразу готовые значения для цвета. Ну или пропишите какие хотите цвета надо в палитре по индексам, чтобы карта без изменений выглядела как надо, например `pal.Entries[1] = Color.Blue`, всё просто должно быть. Всего 256 цветов, простор для творчества большой.

Либо если вы хотите отображать только конкретные значения с карты, а остальные оставить черными, то можете палитру сделать например так

```
ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;
pal.Entries[0] = Color.Black;
pal.Entries[1] = Color.Blue;
for (int c = 2; c < 256; c++)
    pal.Entries[c] = Color.Black;
bmp.Palette = pal;
```

Тогда скопировать в битмап полученный массив можно почти моментально вот так:

```
public void CopyToBitmap(byte[] map, Bitmap bmp)
{
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        bmp.PixelFormat);
    Marshal.Copy(map, 0, bmpData.Scan0, map.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

```
byte[] map = new byte[1920 * 1080];
CopyToBitmap(map, bmp);
```

Без `unsafe` кода даже получается. Готовый битмап кладете в интерфейс и готово. Так как копирование данных идет целиком, то не потребуется очищать битмап передо копированием, данные перезапишутся полностью.

Comment: Вау... Ваше предложение увеличило скорость почти 2 раза. Теперь 30-35 поколений в секунду. Примерно 16мс на копирование массива Map в BitMap. Это чудо какое-то.... Вы Гений спасибо большое

Comment: @SevaVorobev вы не поверите, но карту можно вообще рисовать прямо в битмап, минуя копирование массива. Развлекайтесь. Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив галочку слева от ответа. Кстати 16мс что-то многовато, либо вы замеряете не только чистое копирование, а еще что-то, либо что-то тормозит. О, соберите релизный вариант проекта, вы же в отладке. Время замерять надо в релизе.

Comment: Вы правы копирование происходить за 0мс. А вот на обновление pictureBox уходить как раз примерно 15-16мс(picturebox.Refresh()). Замеры в Release версии, сборка оптимизирована замер с помощью StopWatch

Comment: Метод Refresh() занимал около 15-17мс. Заменил его на Invalidate(). Теперь отрисовка меньше миллисекунды. И в итоге скорость выросла до 60-65 поколений в секунду. Теперь все уперлось только лишь в алгоритм подсчета соседей который занимает 17мс