# Отрисовка пикселей в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Начал писать 2D движок и сразу-же столкнулся с проблемой.

Я не знаю как отрисовать конкретного цвета, в конкретном месте пиксель. Проект чистый, только с внешним видом окна поигрался.

Comment: Насколько я помню, можно использовать PictureBox и рисовать пикселы в нём

Comment: 2D движок в WinForms 

Comment: @iiKuzmychov Ну надо же с чего-то начинать! Хотя проще конечно взять `Unity 3D` и не мучиться )

Comment: Если вы делаете действительно правильный UI/2D движок, пусть даже на базе Winforms, то вам нужно научиться контролы рисовать векторной графикой, а не пиксели. Научитесь переопределять `OnPaint` и использовать `Graphics`. Ну и учите ООП и всё такое. Для отрисовки растровых спрайтов вам уже верно подсказали, подойдет `PictureBox`. В свою очередь `PictureBox` ничего сам не рисует, он просто отображает `Bitmap`. Рисовать надо будет на битмапе.

Comment: @iiKuzmychov не стоит недооценивать GDI+, вполне себе вменяемый 2D движок "для домохозяек".

Comment: @CrazyElf Зачем мне создавать "Жизнь" в юнити? чтобы больше места ела? нет спасибо, лучше написать самому. Плюс саму "Жизнь" я уже писал, но только в виде двухслойного массива 0 и 1.

Comment: @ДенисБас Ну так то да, я после каких-то курсов по `C#` к примеру `Arcanoid` писал на `WinForms`, прикольно было. Но на `Unity` всё-равно потом если научиться гораздо проще всё будет делать и быстрее, не говоря уже про продвинутость.

Comment: Ах Жизнь, ну тогда вот вам [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1462094/373567) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1462172/373567), одного пикчербокса хватит. Вот вам еще [Хабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/505606/)