# Поиск границ области изображения с одинаковым цветом C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, изображения, opencv

У меня есть растровое изображение с несколькими тысячами фигур уникальных цветов и  неправильной формы. Я хочу получить границы каждой фигуры как список точек, чтобы в дальнейшем с ними взаимодействовать, например на их основе сделать векторные фигуру.
Сначала пробовал использовать за основу метод flood fill с разными вариантами алгоритмов - точки добавлялись в список не последовательно и часто пропуская пограничные пиксели, из-за чего попытка соединить их веткорами выдавала полную несуразицу.
Узнал про "Цепной код Фримена", который идеально подходит для моей задачи - но гугл про него выдаёт только древние статьи про матлаб без малейших намёков на хотя бы псевдокод, не говоря уже про пример из языков семейства C.

OpenCV мне не подходит, потому что тот переводит изображение в чисто серую цветовую схему. Может я не до конца разобрался в OpenCV, но 255 цветов серой градации мне явно не подойдёт, потому что оперировать нужно с 1 или 2 тысячами уникальных цветов. Если есть варианты обхода, то это будет просто прекрасно.

Прошу, подскажите возможные варианты решения задачи. Любые алгоритмы, способы, обязательно с наглядным примером или демо-проектом.

Примерный вид исходного изображения:

[image]

Comment: opencv умеет работать далеко не только с чёрно-белой картинкой, тут вы вправду не разобрались просто

Comment: _OpenCV мне не подходит_ а метка тогда зачем?

Comment: для C# есть неплохой пакет emgu.cv, который обёртывает вызовы openc

Comment: @iiKuzmychov в популярных примерах и статьях по opencv используют серую градацию. По крайней мере из того что нашёл, поэтому и возник вопрос.

Comment: Хоть бы пример картинки показали, у меня с воображением плохо. А вообще вот какие штуки есть: [Оператор Собеля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) и [Оператор Кэнни](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%9A%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8), наглядный пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ibBYinRiEA

Comment: @iiKuzmychov покопав гугл пришёл к выводу что для работы с тремя каналами цветов требуется либо разбивать изображение с помощью Split, либо вытаскивать определённый цвет с помощью Sub. Но как это правильно использовать для моей задачи - не знаю, ибо всё что нашёл, так это  несколько вопросов на англоязычном stackoverflow с малосодержательными ответами. Документация по emgucv тоже малосодержательна.
Проблема в том что почему-то не создаются маски и игнорируется ThresholdBinary - контур находится у группы цветов вместо нужного мне уникального цвета.

Comment: @iiKuzmychov Также интересно: мне требуется чтобы контур находился внутри фигуры и с максимальной точностью. Если использовать Erode, то на контур начинает действовать некое сглаживание и в итоге контур перестаёт идти точно вдоль границы фигуры, игнорируя сложные, тонкие части фигур.  Есть ли другой способ вынести контур внутрь фигуры без таких потерь?
Кстати пример изображения с которым работаю я приложил к вопросу.

Comment: @Domed erode это функция которая расширяет границы, если вам она не нужна, просто не используйте её. Вы, по-сути, через emgu.cv пишите pipeline обработки изображения